# rabbitmq publishing to exchange throws 404 even after assertExchange

Tags: node.js, express, events, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ `amqplib` package in order to emit and subscribe to events in my express application.

This is how I implemented the event emiting:

Initialization:

```
  const connection = await rabbitmq.connect(Config.RabbitMQConnectionString);
  this.channel = await connection.createChannel();
```

Emit function:

```
  public async emit(eventName: string, data: any): Promise<void> {
    const event = {
      data,
      eventName
    };

    this.channel.assertExchange(eventName, 'fanout', { durable: false });

    const serializedData = JSON.stringify(event);
    this.channel.publish(eventName, '', Buffer.from(serializedData));
  }
```

Usage:

```
eventBus.emit('some.event.name', { someData: true } );
```

As you can see, before every `channel.publish` I'm making sure the exchange exists using `channel.assertExchange`, so why do I get the following message?

> {"code":404,"classId":60,"methodId":40,"level":"error","message":"Channel
> closed by server: 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no
> exchange 'some.event.name' in vhost '/'" Channel closed by server:
> 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange
> 'some.event.name' in vhost

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that what was missing is that I didn't wait for the `assertExchange` task to finish.

`await this.channel.assertExchange(eventName, 'fanout', { durable: false });`